# Optimizing check value

Tags: python, string, optimization, tuples

Is there any way to optimize this code so it can be shorter?

```
if user_input[0] == "f" or user_input[0:2] == "mu" or user_input[0:2] == "he" or user_input[-1] == "a":
```

I thought about using a tuple

```
inputcheck = ('f', 'mu', 'he', 'a')
```

but then would run into problems when trying to actually check the different options

```
if user_input == inputcheck #This would of course not work
if user_input[0] == inputcheck #This may work, but 'a' needs to be checked at -1 index of string not at the start
```

Comment: Often [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) are the easiest way to compactly match various things.  Using `|` allows you to match any of several sub-expressions.  But if all you are trying to is what you wrote (ie, match those 4 conditions), then your current solution is pretty decent.

Comment: you could do a regex, but then you'd have two problems.  I would probably think about what the data inside user_input represents and convert it into a more logical structure.  Maybe even an object then then you could do something like UserInput(user_input).has_fmuhea()

Comment: @craigb I'm trying to match those exact conditions, my problem is that i'll need to recall various times the check so I thought there might be a way of making it... "simpler"? or easier to recall

Comment: @toppk the user input is the name, and I need to specifically check in said locations wether said checks are; that's why has_fmuhea() won't work I think

Comment: @Remi what I am suggesting is that if user_input has different data elements inside one string, they should be decomposed into a different datastructure that stores the data elements differently.  but if these checks are just for a single data element, then something like a regex may be useful. for example, you don't want to use a regex on an xml string.  you convert the xml to a tree object and traverse it.

Comment: @toppk ok! it's only user input so I assume regex will work, off to learn what they are and how to use them!

Answer (score 2):

A way to shorten it would be:

```
if user_input[0] == "f" or user_input[0:2] in ["mu", "he"] or user_input[-1] == "a":
```

the `in` allows checking of the list values

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use regex and all you want to check is prefixes and suffixes, you can use [str.startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and [str.endswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith), e.g.:

```py
if user_input.startswith("mu")...
```

This way, you don't have to match the substring range to the length of the prefix.

A common way to test if a predicate is true for any of a list of values is using python's builtin [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function in conjunction with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```py
if any(user_input.startswith(prefix) for prefix in ["f", "mu", "he"])...
```

If you need some functionality more than once (as you mentioned in a comment), you can extract it into a function, e.g.:

```py
PREFIXES = ("f", "mu", "he")
SUFFIXES = ("a",)

def check_user_input(user_input: str) -> bool:
    return any(user_input.startswith(prefix) for prefix in PREFIXES) or any(
        user_input.endswith(suffix) for suffix in SUFFIXES
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, a (dirty) solution may be using regular expressions,

```py
import re

user_input = input()

if re.search(r"^f|^mu|^ha|a$",user_input):
    print("works!!")
```

Comment: this checks if the text start with `f`, `mu` or `ha`, or ends with `a`

Comment: Thar does the r after 'if re.search(' means/stands for?

Comment: @Remi, that means that is a literal string, don't accept the escape character "\", this is useful when you need use the char "\" like a normal character